# Laravel-mix : using `mix.js` or `mix.scripts`

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

With Laravel 5.5 I'm using laravel-mix to compile my assets.

However something is not clear to me: what is the difference between `mix.js` and `mix.scripts` and why would I use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mix.scripts will

> ...combine and minify any number of JavaScript files... This option is particularly useful for legacy projects where you don't require Webpack compilation for your JavaScript.

While mix.js will compile ES2015, bundle modules if any and also compile vue components.